# I am using react-native-swiper-flatlist , but my image is not displaying i don't know error

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

//     My deals
const Deals =[{
id:'1',
imageUrl:
'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg/800px-Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg',

```
},
{
  id:'2',
  imageUrl:
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg/800px-Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg',


},
{
  id:'3',
  imageUrl:
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg/800px-Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg',


},
{
  id:'4',
  imageUrl:
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg/800px-Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg',


},


]


export default () => {
  return (
    <SwiperFlatList
      autoplay
      autoplayDelay={5}
      index={3}
      autoplayLoop
      autoplayInvertDirection
      data={Deals}
      renderItem={ Deals  => { return <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri:Deals.imageUrl}} />}}
      showPagination
            PaginationComponent={CustomPagination}

    />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
  image: {
    height: height * 0.5,
    width,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with the image style.

instead of this:

```
image: {
  height: height * 0.5,
  width,
},
```

try setting fixed values, or window-size related values, like:

```
image: {
  height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.5,
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, this solution did not solve it.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Make sure to import the Dimensions API from react-native: ```import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'```